# How can I use UniversalClassLoader in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

Symfony uses the classloader class in its autoloader.. I have seen tutorials that use the UniversalClassLoader instead of the classLoader class. For instance this adding external libraries requires the Universal class loader ..

```
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

This line gets a classLoader class. How can I use a UniversalclassLoader in this case?

Comment: Symfony2 relies on Composers autoloader as of 2.1 and that is, what is  within `vendor/autoload.php`. Refer composer for further details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Symfony2.0` Symfony uses there own [ClassLoader Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/class_loader.html). You can find the documentation about how to use this class on the link I just gave.
However, this class is initialized in the `app/autoload.php` file, which is not the file you referred to.

`Symfony2.1` uses [composer](http://getcomposer.org/) to handle the dependencies. Composer automatically add a classloader to easily autoload load all dependencies. This class is initialized in the `vendor/autoload.php` file, which you refer to. The documentation about this classloader can be found at [the composer documentation](http://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading).